# Replace multiple items in a string

Tags: php

i've scraped a html string from a website. In this string it contains multiple strings like `color:#0269D2`. How can i make `str_replace` code which replace this string with another `color` ?

For instance something like this just looping through all `color:#0269D` in the `fulltext` string variable?

```
str_replace("color:#0269D","color:#000000",$fulltext);
```

Comment: You don't have to loop through to replace all instances of the same thing. From the str_replace manual, "str_replace — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string"

Answer (score 0):

you pass array to str_replace function , no need to use loop

```
$a= array("color:#0269D","color:#000000");

$str= str_replace($a,"", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right syntax. I would add a check:

```
$newText = str_replace("color:#0269D", "color:#000000", $fulltext, $count);
if($count){
    echo "Replaced $count occurrences of 'color'.";
}
```

This code might be too greedy for what you're looking to do. Careful. Also if the string differs at all, for example `color: #0269D`, this replacement will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

’str_replace’ already replaces all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string.

If you want to replace all colors but aren't sure which hexcodes you'll find you could use `preg_replace` to match multiple occurrences of a pattern with a regular expression and replace it.

In your case:

```
$str = "String with loads of color:#000000";
$pattern = '/color ?: ?#[0-9a-f]{3,6}/i';
$replacement = "color:#FFFFFF";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```